# Best way to solve for $(1+a)^{-n}=1-\frac{I}{C}a$

Tags: approximation, binomial-theorem

Best way to solve for $a$ for an equation that reads:

$$
C\cdot\frac{1-(1+a)^{-n}}{a}=I; n\geq 1.
$$

This can be rewritten into:

$$
(1+a)^{-n}=1-\frac{I}{C}a.
$$

One way to do it maybe is set $b=a+1$ and $X=\frac{I}{C}$, which would give:

$$
\frac{1}{b^n}=1-X(b-1).
$$

Is there a meaningful solution to find $a$?

Comment: what denotes $n$ here?

Comment: _n_ is an integer, greater than 0

Comment: For what variable do you want to solve for?

Comment: If you multiply through by $b^n$ you have a polynomial of degree $n+1$ in $b$. This is unlikely to have a nice solution for $n > 3$. Numerical methods will work.

Comment: sorry, @JaideepKhare, I wasn't clear. I'll edit the problem

Comment: @EthanBolker It isn't nice either for $n=2,3$. It is just what is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got a polynomial equation in $b$ of degree "$n+1$"

$Xb^{n+1}-(X+1)b^n+1=0$

Sadly, we don't have any closed form solution for $b$ in terms of $n$.

Answer (score 0):

for $n=1$ we get $$a=0$$ or $$a=\frac{C-J}{J}$$
for $n=2$ we get
$$a=0,a=\frac{C-2J+\sqrt{C^2+4CJ}}{J}, a=\frac{1}{2}\frac{C-2J-\sqrt{C^2+4CJ}}{J}$$
for $n=3$ the solution looks complicated